# force PostgreSQL into recovery mode

Tags: postgresql

I have a somewhat strange question.

Is there a way to manually force PostgreSQL into recovery mode?
I've not been able to find anything in the documentation.

I've been working with a script monitoring a PostgreSQL database and need to do some testing.

Comment: Look at the 8. point at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-PITR-RECOVERY or the beginning paragraph of http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/warm-standby.html

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [pg_standby](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstandby.html).

I cannot gurantee it, though, as I haven't tried it.